# Why can't WHS2011 publish xxx.homeserver.com address for using DynDNS?

Tags: networking, windows-home-server, windows-server, dynamic-dns

Because I switched to another ISP I had to reconfigure everything. Now I want to be able to use the subdomain provided by Microsoft: xxx.homeserver.com

I manually configured the port forwarding and it is working. If I go to **Server settings** > **Remote Web Access** I get an error:

> The router is not working

If I go on **Repair** I get

> Remote web access is blocked on this server

[image]

The link points to [this site](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/remote-connectivity-support-2.aspx). UPnP is activated on my router and the ports 80, 443, 4125 are forwarded to the WHS. I verified that they are working (I can access the weblogin). What do I have to do to make this working? Is this a problem with the router? So UPnP is not correctly implemented? The router model is Huawei B593s. The links states that I can manually configure it. That's what I've done. The internet is working and I also reserved an IP address for the WHS.

How can I get the DynDNS service running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it is working, but I haven't done anything. Now he is writing **available** under web access. Perhaps it needs some (long) time for refreshing.